# Decarta - how to refresh map

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am using the Decarta JS API.  I am displaying a map with layers.  I want to refresh the map and redraw new layers, but I see no way to do this in the [documentation](http://developer.decarta.com/static/JS4/files.html).

Is there a way to refresh the map using the API?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to refresh a single overlay and not the entire map, you can do this:

`myOverlay.render(myMap.tileGrid);`

Assuming of course myMap is a deCarta.Core.Map and myOverlay is a deCarta.Core.MapOverlay.

If the size of map container changed, you need to do the following so that the required tiles are loaded after the resize:

```
myMap.resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, I am able to accomplish my desired results by simply removing all children from the designated container the map is added to:

```
$('#mapContainer').empty();
```

I feel this is a crude way to handle this functionality and am hoping someone knows a more elegant way.